# Vaadin frontend build reproducibly hang in pnpm installation

Tags: node.js, vaadin, pnpm

I am having issues getting my Vaadin application to run (in development mode) or to fully pack (in production mode. The former hangs in "Frontend compilation", the latter in maven step "build-frontend", which in my understanding does the same but during compile time, so that the compiled frontend code can be packed up for distribution).

Regardless of whether node.js is installed before or not (I tried with both sitations) the frontend compilation or frontend building, resp. fails (i.e. hangs forever) in the step "installing pnpm version 4.4.0 locally". See the below output from the console.

Apparently the Vaadin maven plugin expects a different pnpm version (range >=4.4.0, <4.6.0) than what gets installed with the node version (I used the latest LTS version node-v14.17.0-x64.msi which installs pnpm v6.7.1). See the below console output.

If no node.js is installed beforehand, then the Vaadin build downloads and installs the very same version 14.17.0 (which of course also installs the same pnpm 6.7.1) and ends in the very same error.

What can I do to get this working and being able to build and execute vaadin applications again? This used to work until about mid of last week, i.e. end of May 2021, when this suddely seized to work (even though I haven't - at least not consciously - changed anything related to node/npm/pnpm on my system).

```
...
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:18.0.2:build-frontend (default) @ kstazh-monitoring ---
[INFO] Scanning classes to find frontend configurations and dependencies...
[INFO] Visited 748 classes. Took 1460 ms.
[INFO] Visited 109 classes. Took 51 ms.
[INFO] writing file D:\Projects\KStA_ZH_Monitoring\code\application\target\flow-frontend\package.json.
[INFO] writing file D:\Projects\KStA_ZH_Monitoring\code\application\target\flow-frontend\form\package.json.
[INFO] writing file 'D:\Projects\KStA_ZH_Monitoring\code\application\target\index.html'
[INFO] writing file 'D:\Projects\KStA_ZH_Monitoring\code\application\target\index.ts'
[INFO] Parsing java files from [D:\Projects\KStA_ZH_Monitoring\code\application\src\main\java]
[INFO] There are no connect endpoints to generate.
[INFO] Added 43 dependencies to main package.json
[INFO] writing file D:\Projects\KStA_ZH_Monitoring\code\application\package.json.
[INFO] Running `pnpm install` to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies. This may take a moment, please stand by...
[INFO] Generated pnpmfile hook file: 'D:\Projects\KStA_ZH_Monitoring\code\application\pnpmfile.js'
[WARNING] installed pnpm ('C:\Users\mmo\AppData\Roaming\npm\pnpm.cmd', version 6.7.1) is not in the compatible versions range (>=4.4.0, <4.6.0)
[INFO] installing pnpm version 4.4.0 locally
[WARNING] installed pnpm ('C:\Users\mmo\AppData\Roaming\npm\pnpm.cmd', version 6.7.1) is not in the compatible versions range (>=4.4.0, <4.6.0)
[INFO] installing pnpm version 4.4.0 locally
<at this position the build hangs forever>
```

BTW: does anyone know which node.js version came with a pnpm version in [4.4.0-4.6.0)?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a new project downloaded from start.vaadin.com?
Node.js comes with npm, it does not include pnpm. Could you check if you actually have pnpm installed globally by running `pnpm --version` in command prompt? You might also try deleting `C:\Users\mmo\.vaadin` (where Vaadin installs node/pnpm) and trying the project again.

Comment: Yes - I did that with a freshly created and downloaded HelloWorld app from the Vaadin homepage. Same issue. I also did an entire "Vaadin dance" and more meanwhile. I also uninstalled pnpm 6.7.1. and installed 4.4.0, but the frontend builds still all hung. As I just had to learn, on another system that still has node.js v4.10.0 installed (and without pnpm) the frontend build worked fine and the application executed. I thus suspect the issue to be with node 4.17.0. Will try to downgrade my own system to 4.10.0 later today and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I guess you created this issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11162 it's probably easier to continue debugging/discussion there.

Comment: yes - I had a longer session yesterday evening with knoobie. But we both ran out of steam (or rather ideas).

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the solution from GitHub:

Uninstalling everything node/npm/pnpm related from the computer and starting fresh fixed the problem. The situation was probably related to some version incompatibility, some update getting messed up, or something not getting cleaned properly, but exact cause wasn't discovered.